# Internal error when calling cakePHP app from network

Tags: php, apache, cakephp

I have a CakePHP application running on a Apache server wich is currently working on the local loop. However when I call it with its network IP it throws an internal error. I mean:

When I call

```
   localhost/myApp
```

everything works fine.

However:

```
 192.168.x.x/myApp
```

Throws error 500:

Fatal Error

```
 Error: Call to undefined function curl_init()
```

Any idea or clue what could be wrong here?

Comment: You're using virtual hosts and your web server doesn't know what to reply when no host header is supplied.